# Chosen Plug-in DropDownList Not Updating

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I'm using the [Chosen DDL Plug-in](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and creating a DDL based on other items chosen.

The first DDL is populated on load with a list of items for the user to choose from. Once a user chooses an item from this list, I display a second DDL for them to choose an item type. This then populates a third DDL. This third DDL is not doing the Chosen update.

The `select` items are as follows:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="">
            <td style="width: 33%;">
                <select id="ddlOne">
                    <option value="placeholder">-- Select --</option>
                    @for (int n = 0; n < Model.Count; n++)
                    {
                        <option value="@Model[n]">@Model[n]</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; display:none;" id="tdDbItemType">
                <select id="ddlItemtype">
                    <option value="placeholder">-- Select --</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; display:none;" id="tdDbItemName">
                <select id="ddlItemName" style="width:33%;"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I create these `Chosen` DDL's like this:

```
$('#ddlItemtype').chosen({
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing was found!",
    width: "95%",
    search_contains: true // allows for a user to do a contains search
});

$('#ddlOne').chosen({
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing was found!",
    width: "95%",
    search_contains: true // allows for a user to do a contains search
});

$('#ddlItemName').chosen({   // if I remove this, I can use the originally select, without utilizing the Chosen features/styling
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing was found!",
    width: "95%",
    search_contains: true // allows for a user to do a contains search
});
```

These are above the `chosen.change()` sections in the script

On the change event of `ddlItemType` I do this:

```
$('#ddlItemtype').chosen().change(function () {
    $('.waiting').show(); // spinning wheel gif
    var objSelectedItemType = $('#ddlItemtype').find('option:selected');
    var sSelectedItemType = objSelectedItemType[0].innerText;
    sItemType = sSelectedItemType;
    LoadItemList(sSelectedItemType);
    $('.waiting').hide();
    //$('#ddlItemName').chosen().trigger('chosen:updated'); // $(...).chosen is not a function
});
```

and inside `LoadItemList()`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Database/GetDatabaseItemList/",
        data: { "": id },
        success: function (response) {
            var sHtml = '';
            $('#ddlDatabaseItemName').empty();
            sHtml = '<option value="placeholder">' + '-- Select Item --' + '</option>';
            try {
                for (var n = 0; n < response.length; n++) {
                    sHtml += '<option value="' + response[n] + '">' + response[n] + '</option>';
                }
                $('#ddlItemName').html(sHtml);
                $('#tdDbItemName').show();
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Error in the ajax: " + e);
                return false;
            }
            finally {
                $('#ddlItemName').trigger('chosen:updated');
                console.log('LoadItemList worked well');
            }
        }
    });
```

When I inspect the original `select` item after this `AJAX` call, the options have been added to the `select` item but I am unable to update the `Chosen` DDL.

All of this resides outside of the `$(document).ready();`

I'm using `jQuery 3.2.1` and I've tried both `1.8.2` and `1.7.0` versions of `Chosen`.

EDIT: Added the HTML markup and the `chosen().change()` that triggers the `AJAX` call

EDIT2: The Final answer was a combo of Master Yoda's answer below and there being another reference to jQuery in my `_Layout,cshmtl` page. Once I implemented Master Yoda's approach and removed this last jQuery reference, it began working wonderfully.

Comment: Did you include JQuery.js BEFORE Jquery.Chosen.js?

Comment: @MasterYoda Yes -- jquery is the first thing. The other DDL's work fine with Chosen, it is just this update issue.

Comment: Are you sure you can chain .chosen() with .trigger()?

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on your ReloadItemDDL() method in javascript console to see whats actually happening

Comment: @MasterYoda Some of the examples I found on SO indicated to chain them, so it is something I tried. There were no errors or anything when stepping into .trigger('chosen:updated')

Comment: can you add your HTML markup please? also add the js that hides your select element

Comment: What is this ---> #ddlToTriggerChange?

Comment: This process happens as a chain of events. So in my first DDL (also chosen) I select something and display the next DDL (chosen). Once an option in the second DDL is picked, the third one is dynamically created, but doesn't update with Chosen. ddlToTriggerChange is the second DDL that calls the function to populate the problem DDL. @MasterYoda

Comment: Please put your full code up, its hard to know where to start if i dont see it :)

Comment: @MasterYoda thanks for all the help. I've added more detailed code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error might be occurring within the callback of your AJAX request:

```js
$('#ddlItemtype').chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing was found!",
  width: "95%",
  search_contains: true // allows for a user to do a contains search
});

$('#ddlOne').chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing was found!",
  width: "95%",
  search_contains: true // allows for a user to do a contains search
});

$('#ddlItemName').chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing was found!",
  width: "95%",
  search_contains: true // allows for a user to do a contains search
});

$('#ddlItemtype').chosen().change(function() {
  $('.waiting').show(); // spinning wheel gif
  var objSelectedItemType = $('#ddlItemtype').find('option:selected');
  var sSelectedItemType = objSelectedItemType[0].innerText;
  sItemType = sSelectedItemType;
  LoadItemList(sSelectedItemType);
  $('.waiting').hide();
});

//used in place of your AJAX call
function LoadItemList(id) 
{
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Database/GetDatabaseItemList/",
        data: { "": id },
        success: function (response) 
        {
          //this will obviously fail here
          //added logic to error method instead
        },
        error: function(response)
        {
            try 
            {
              //use empty instead of .html('')
              $('#ddlItemName').empty();

              //build up your list of items
              for (var n = 1; n <= 10; n++) 
              {
                $('#ddlItemName').append('<option> item name ' + n + '</option');
              }                         
                 //call this in your success callback method
                 $("#ddlItemName").chosen().trigger("chosen:updated");
              } 
            catch (err) 
            {
              alert("error caught");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="">
      <td style="width: 33%;">
        <select id="ddlOne">
          <option value="placeholder">--Select --</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 33%;" id="tdDbItemType">
        <select id="ddlItemtype">
          <option value="placeholder">-- Select --</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 33%;" id="tdDbItemName">
        <select id="ddlItemName" style="width:33%;"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll get my html for it up in a minute. Doing this, I still get `$(...).chosen is not a function`

Comment: First make sure that you are definitely referencing the Jquery.min.js and chosen.jquery.js libraries with jquery referenced first, I recommend testing this with a hosted CDN to make sure you aren't missing anything. Try this one: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chosen. Then move your scripts into a $(document).ready() function and test again. Somewhere along the line the chosen() method isnt initialised

Comment: Even better, update your question with SO code snippet

Comment: I updated my code. I can use `chosen` in other places, which is why I am so confused as to why it isn't working inside. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I switched out the references to Chosen and jQuery and now the error is a bit different, but still a `chosen is not a function` error... https://gyazo.com/8dd1fce05ac04dff03f42d36c00a5ca6

Comment: This is the answer, but `$('ddlItemName').trigger('chosen:updated');` in the AJAX

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance!

Comment: Awesome, i knew there had to be another reference to Jquery somewhere.